# Satellite grids around other planets

Tags: solar-system, gas-giants

We send a lot of rovers to Mars, as interesting as the planet could possibly be.  But why are we not putting satellite grids around planets that could transmit superficial probe data at the very least?  That seems to me like a much more interesting project.

Comment: Most other planets or other destinations have 0 or at most 1 spacecraft around them so the need for orbiters to act as relay satellites as Mars Odyssey does for the Martian rovers isn't there.

Comment: This seems that it would be better suited to the space exploration site.

Comment: Lol, so I guess we can just forget this question.  But I did mean "grids".

Comment: The answer to "Why are we not putting satellite grids around planets..." is that money is not infinite and what there is is (supposedly) being spent in the most effective way possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not on-topic in Astronomy SE as defined in the help center. However questions about how space exploration missions are planned, evaluated, funded and  carried out *are on topic* in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/).